# how to ignore tags file errors in vim

Tags: vim, ctags

For some reason I have errors in tags file generated by ctags.
Have tried to solve the errors by changing ctags options, did no good.
Now I would like to try another approach - make vim ignore errors in the tags file.
Is it possible?
The tags file contains lines that are not tags, just sentences taken from somewhere in the code, I guess.
The tag file is quite large:

```
$ wc tags
591708  3711802 65594557 tags
```

e.g.:

```
$grep -vn -C 1 "\/" tags
510630-packet   ISS/code/opensource/ssl/ssl.h   /^  unsigned char *packet;$/;"  m   struct:ssl_st
510631:packet that is present on the network wire. Even if an inbound packet is denied
510632-packetSrcAdr ISS/code/future/ospf/inc/osfssnmp.h /^    tIPADDR    packetSrcAdr;$/;"  m   struct:_IfConfErrTrapInfo
```

found out that there is a faq.tex file that many 'sentences' come from it. I'm trying to exclude it from ctags (--exclude)

Comment: What about showing us those "sentences"?

Comment: Could it be that the source files causing "sentences" in the tags file are not exactly in the language supported by ctags? I've seen horrible things done with C macros that any non-C-preprocessor would have difficulties with parsing.

Comment: line 510631 has an error.

Answer (score 0):

If the corrupted lines in the tags file match some pattern (regex), you could fix-up the tags file. e.g. place this in your `Makefile`:

```
tags:
     ctags -f $@.tmp ...
     grep -v 'pattern of bogus tag lines' $@.tmp > $@
     rm $@.tmp
```

Comment: tried this approach as well. Can't regex all the errors. :-(

Comment: @RanRegev Can you please post a small sample of input that causes a corrupt line in the tags file? We don't have much to work with other than "ctags doesn't grok something".

Comment: Then grep for *proper* ctags lines with something like `grep '/\^.*/;"'`. If these don't appear in "sentences" you have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to look for the origin of the lines with the error and try to eliminate those lines / files, causing the errors in the tags file.